# jOOQ join Select<?> object

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I want to perform something like this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  tbl1 t1 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(col1) as maxCol, col2 FROM tbl1 t1 GROUP BY t1.col2) subQ
  ON t1.col2 = subQ.col2
  AND t1.col1 = subQ.maxCol
```

In jOOQ, I store the `subQ` into `Select<?>` object:

```java
Select<?> subQ = myDSL.select(DSL.max(TBL1.COL1).as("maxCol"), TBL1.COL2)
                      .from(TBL1)
                      .groupBy(TBL1.COL2);
```

My question is, how to get the `maxCol` column from `subQ` and use it in `join`? My `join` is something like this:

```java
select()
.from(TBL1)
.join(subQ.asTable())
.on(TBL1.COL1.eq(subQ.asTable().field("maxCol")));
```

I have error on `.on()`

> The method eq(String) in the type Field is not applicable for the arguments (Field)

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using MySQL 8.0

If you're using MySQL 8.0+, don't use a subquery but a window function instead. This would be the equivalent query to yours:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t1.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.col2 ORDER BY col1 DESC) rk
  FROM tbl1 t1
) t
WHERE t.rk = 1
```

The advantage is that you only have a single `tbl1` access, which is likely to run faster.

[This is often also called a `TOP-n` query. In other databases, there are other ways to implement this, see this article here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/).

#### Using older MySQL versions

If you access a field by untyped name (`String` or [`org.jooq.Name`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Name.html)) from any table, then the compiler does not have any type information to put on the resulting `Field<?>`, which is why your original code doesn't compile.

You can, however, use one of the following techniques:

#### Remember the original `maxCol` field reference

From your subquery, factor out the `maxCol` field reference and assign it to a local variable (assuming it is of type `Integer`, replace if needed):

```java
Field<Integer> maxCol = DSL.max(TBL1.COL1).as("maxCol");
Select<?> subQ = myDSL.select(maxCol, TBL1.COL2).from(TBL1).groupBy(TBL1.COL2);
```

Now, you can also use this reference to extract a column from the subquery:

```java
Field<Integer> subQMaxCol = subQ.field(maxCol);
```

Or inline that directly in your solution:

```java
select().from(TBL1)
        .join(subQ.asTable())
        .on(TBL1.COL1.eq(subQ.field(maxCol)));
```

#### Name your `maxCol` column after `TBL1.COL1`

In this particular use-case, it might make sense not to introduce any new names, but to re-use `COL1` as a name:

```java
Select<?> subQ = myDSL.select(DSL.max(TBL1.COL1).as(TBL1.COL1), TBL1.COL2)
                      .from(TBL1)
                      .groupBy(TBL1.COL2);
```

In this case (if there is no ambiguous `COL1` column name), you can use that reference to extract the `COL1` field again from the subquery:

```java
select().from(TBL1)
        .join(subQ.asTable())
        .on(TBL1.COL1.eq(subQ.field(TBL1.COL1)));
```

#### Use the `TBL1.COL1` reference's data type

From your original solution, just add the data type when you extract the field from the subquery:

```java
select().from(TBL1)
        .join(subQ.asTable())
        .on(TBL1.COL1.eq(subQ.field("maxCol", TBL1.COL1.getDataType())));
```

Or, coerce it:

```java
select().from(TBL1)
        .join(subQ.asTable())
        .on(TBL1.COL1.eq(subQ.field("maxCol").coerce(TBL1.COL1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve the problem:

```
select().from(TBL1).join(subQ.asTable()).on(TBL1.COL1.eq((Field<DataType>) subQ.field("maxCol")));
```